# Display posts from an array of ID's

Tags: wp-query, id

The result of the query so far is the print of the array, Array ( [0] => 309 [1] => 10 ), 309 & 10 are the correct id's of the posts I want to display, and "No posts were found" the result of hitting "else".

I have a pastebin with the most up to date copy of my code here, http://pastebin.com/pZkQCf9y

Here is the query:

```
<?php

$ongoing_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'promotions',
  'meta_key' => 'sp_ongoingPromotion',
  'meta_value' => 1
);

$current_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'promotions',
  'meta_key' => 'sp_endDate',
  'meta_value' => date("Y/m/d"),
  'meta_compare' => '>=',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);

// Get promotions using the arguments outlined above.
$ongoing_promotions = get_posts( $ongoing_args );
$current_promotions = get_posts( $current_args );

// Merge arrays
$all_promotions = array_merge( $ongoing_promotions, $current_promotions );

// Get just the ID of promotions
$promotion_ids = wp_list_pluck( $all_promotions, 'ID' );
print_r($promotion_ids);

// Do a new query with these IDs to get a properly-sorted list of promotions
$args = array(
  'post__in' => $promotion_ids,
  'numberposts' => 5,
  'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query( $args );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($wp_query->have_posts()){
        while($wp_query->have_posts()){
            $wp_query->the_post();
?>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: i'm not sure this will help but i'd delete lines 34 - 36. They look to be redundant. what type of post are you querying for (page, post, CPT)? if its a CPT you'll need to add 'post_type' => 'whatever your CPT is' to the $args array. let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: It was the missing 'post_type' I thought having already declared 'post_type' further up I wouldn't need to have done it again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you set the `fields` parameter to ids you will get an array of ids instead of unneeded post data ex:

```
$ongoing_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'promotions',
  'meta_key' => 'sp_ongoingPromotion',
  'meta_value' => 1,
  'fields' => 'ids'
);

$current_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'promotions',
  'meta_key' => 'sp_endDate',
  'meta_value' => date("Y/m/d"),
  'meta_compare' => '>=',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'fields' => 'ids'
);

// Get promotions using the arguments outlined above.
$ongoing_promotions = get_posts( $ongoing_args );
$current_promotions = get_posts( $current_args );

// Merge arrays
$all_promotions = array_merge( $ongoing_promotions, $current_promotions );

$args = array(
  'post__in' => $promotion_ids,
  'numberposts' => 5,
  'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$all_query = new WP_Query($args);
if($all_query->have_posts()){
    while($all_query->have_posts()){
        $all_query->the_post();
        //loop stuff here
    }
}
```